React Native preventing re-rendering of object element in array that is not updated
I am trying to figure out this for days, but my component ImageComponent is flickering when I click add or remove for all the elements in the array. I think the issue is that all elements in the array are re-rendering when one element is updated. How can I fix this? I have been trying using memo and useMemo, as well as useCallback, but none worked... could anyone figure this out, please?
Main
const [addList, setAddList] = useState([
        { name: 'red bull', icon: 'beverage', count: 0 },
        { name: 'beer', icon: 'alcohol', count: 0 }
    ]);

const changeUnitCount = useCallback((index, change) => {
        // console.log('changeUnitCount rendered for', addList[index].name);
        setAddList((prev) => {
            const newCount = prev[index].count + change;
            if (newCount < 0) {
                Alert.alert(`Delete ${prev[index].name}`, 'Are you sure you want to delete this?', [
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        style: 'cancel'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Delete',
                        onPress: () => {
                            setAddList(prev => [...prev.slice(0, index), ...prev.slice(index + 1)]);
                        },
                        style: 'destructive'
                    },
                ]);
            } else {
                const updatedList = [...prev];
                updatedList[index] = { ...updatedList[index], count: newCount };
                return updatedList;
            }
            return prev;
        });
    }, []);

const Unit = React.memo(({ drink, index, changeUnitCount }) => {
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(`${drink.name} component rerendered: ${drink.count}`);
        });
        return (
            <View style={styles.addUnitContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeUnitCount(index, -1)}>
                    <Icon name="remove" color={"#c1dfb0"} size={50} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.addUnit}>
                    <ImageComponent type={'drink'} value={drink.icon} size={30} />
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{drink.name}</Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{drink.count}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeUnitCount(index, 1)}>
                    <Icon name="add" color={"#c1dfb0"} size={50} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    });

return (
    ...
    {addList.map((item, i) => (
                    <Unit key={`${item.name}`} index={i} drink={item} changeUnitCount={changeUnitCount} />
                ))}
);


ImageComponent.jsx
const ImageComponent = memo(({ type, value, size = 30 }) => {
  const source = getImage(type, value);

  if (!source) {
    return null; // Return null if the source is invalid
  }

  console.log(`Image rendered: ${type} ${value}`);

  return (
    <Image
      style={{ width: size, height: size }}
      source={source}
      contentFit="contain"
    />
  );
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.value === nextProps.value && prevProps.size === nextProps.size);

export default ImageComponent;


I have been trying using memo, useMemo, and useCallback to avoid re-rendering of components but did not work. I might have been implementing it incorrectly.

I don't know what you mean by "flicker", but the only issue I see in the code you have shared here is that it looks like you have declared the Unit component inside another React component instead of out on its own. When you redeclare it each render cycle the old one gets unmounted and the new one mounted in its place. Is this what you are possibly seeing, the remounting of the Unit components of the array elements that did not get updated? Move the Unit component out of whatever component code is the first snippet.

Wow you are my life saver. Thanks a lot. Yeah I had all my components inside the main component which forms the whole view. Now I created a new file and component at other place, and it works fine. I just have one question at this point. If  wrap the Unit component inside React component, will it not re-render if I wrap them with useMemo or memo?

It's not "re-rendering", it's re-mounting. No, using the memo Higher Order Component won't fix this as that only helps rerendering issues. The useMemo hook could be used to memoize and provide a stable component function reference, but this also isn't a common practice.
